# How to Redirect Like This

Tags: c#, sharepoint

There is one link in my page which will redirect me to "/Templates/NewsListItem.aspx?id=44318",where 44318 is a page Name whith which I have created a page.Now I have changed a page directory to "News/Pages".So now I want "News/Pages/44318.aspx" i.e.how i can add that .aspx extension to the page so that it will redirect to the appropriate page.

Before this i have tried using mapping Handler FASTCGI approach but didn't worked.SO please help in this case.

Comment: you can handle this in `global.asax` file on `Application_Request` event/method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you really want, try this:

In your method Page_Load from NewsListItem.aspx.cs

```
String fileAspx = Request.QueryString["id"];
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileAspx))
{
 Response.Redirect("~/New/Pages/" + fileAspx + ".aspx");
}
```